# Create user assessment and use results in sql query

Tags: plugins, database, forms

I am building a plugin that displays custom post types based on a user's assessment result. For that I need the user to fill out a form (not a very complicated one). This form submission needs to save the user's identity as well in order for me to pull it from the database.
Is there a plugin that I can use for this assessment or do I need to code my own?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic/out of scope here, can you narrow down your question to a single answerable query? hint: it's okay to ask multiple questions, so long as you have 1 question per question you ask, and it makes it easier for people to answer. Also technical details!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. However, this wasn't a question as to what plugin to use but whether there is one at all. I.e. before I try to code something myself, it is wise to ask whether there is something that exists.

Comment: It was a comment, plugin recommendations are off topic, they may be relevant to you personally but the rules are clear, you would be better off removing that part than arguing on a technicality. If you disagree however then the Meta site is the appropriate place to discuss how the site is ran